# convert string to timestamp and show value to label in swift 2.0

Tags: swift2

I have a code written in objective c so how can i use this code in swift

```
NSString *dateString = [dic2 objectForKey:@"time"];
NSTimeInterval interval = [dateString doubleValue];
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:interval];
NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[format setDateFormat:@"dd MMM, YYYY"];
NSString *datenewString = [format stringFromDate:date];
cellNotification.lbldatenotificationN.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", datenewString];
```

Any help will be appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code.

**Swift 2.3**

```
var dateString = (dic2["time"] as! String)
var interval = dateString.doubleValue
var date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: interval)
var format = NSDateFormatter()
format.dateFormat = "dd MMM, YYYY"
var datenewString = format.stringFromDate(date)
cellNotification.lbldatenotificationN.text = "\(datenewString)"
```

**swift 3.1**

```
var dateString: String? = (dic2["time"] as? String)
var interval: TimeInterval? = dateString?.doubleValue
var date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: interval)
var format = DateFormatter()
format.dateFormat = "dd MMM, YYYY"
var datenewString: String = format.string(from: date)
cellNotification.lbldatenotificationN.text = "\(datenewString)"
```

Comment: It's my pleasure... ;)